# PHP sessions - Get username from sessions stored in database

Tags: php, arrays, json

Since moving session handling over to the database, the $_SESSION array doesn't seem to hold any values which I think is how sessions behave in PHP once the implementation is moved to DB.

This is causing quite a headache for me now. I'm not able to access the username of the user logged in via the details stored in the DB.

Here's my implementation of a function to retrieve the details of a user from the DB.

```
      public function getUser($id, $db) {
        $dbobj->query("SELECT *  FROM SESSION  WHERE id = $id);
        $result = $dbobj->res();
            return $result['data']['use'];
      }
```

`$result` holds the values int he following format

```
array(1) (
[0 => array(3) (
[id => (string) 3fgg67bbsd77bVVgh
[access => (string) 14567893546
[data => (string) luser|s:5"Marke";
)
)
```

I would like `$temp` to hold the value "Marke". How should I parse the resultest returned?

I'd appreciate any help please.

Comment: what do you mean by implementation is moving to DB. are you using any frameworks..??

Comment: Hello Tintu - No frameworks involved. Session handling usually is dealt I memory right ? Instead of this, I have overridden the default implementation to save session details in the database. Would you be able to help me parse the array returned ?

Comment: The user data is in a serialized form, but the serialization is done is in a slightly different way that `serialize()` does. Probably, your framework/library has functions to perform the serialization and unserialization.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`resultset()` function might be not exist.

So you can use this code:

```
public function getSessionUserName($id, $dbobj) {
    $lcid = $id;

    $dbobj->query("SELECT *  FROM SESSION  WHERE id = :sessid");
    $dbobj->bind(':sessid', $lcid);

    // execute query 
    $dbobj->execute();
    // Commented this line
    //$result = $dbobj->resultset();

    // Use fetch() method 
    $result = $dbobj->fetch();

    if ($result) {
        //$temp= $result['data']['luser'];
         $temp= $result['luser']
        return $temp;
    }

 }
```

`$result` will generate following type of output (Output will be based on fields ):

```
Array
(
    [id] => 3fgg67bbsd77bVVgh
    [0] => 3fgg67bbsd77bVVgh
    [access] => 14567893546  
    [1] => 14567893546 
    [luser] => Marke
    [2] => Marke
)
```

Comment: Thank you Uttam. This helps me elsewhere too. Appreciate your help.